# How to dial A, B, C, and D in a phone call?

Tags: calls

Just out of curiosity, how do I dial <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, or <kbd>D</kbd> in a phone call using an Android cell phone? When I open the phone app, I only see the keys in the first 3 columns, i.e. <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, and <kbd>#</kbd>.

I know that <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>D</kbd> aren't used as much as the other 12 keys, but since they're defined, there should be a way I can use them, right?